# “Access violation reading location” error on C++

Tags: c++, destructor, quadtree

I'm a beginner in C++. I have written this code that generates a modified version of Quadtrees. When I run it, I get the "access violation reading location” error. I have two classes:

```
class TreeNode
{
public:
    TreeNode *parent;
    TreeNode *child[4];
    int *id;
    ...
TreeNode(..., int *_id, ...): ..., id(_id),... {}
    };
```

and:

```
class QuadTree
{
private:
    ...
    TreeNode *root;
    void tree_builder(TreeNode *&p,...);

public:
    QuadTree(...);
    ~QuadTree() {delete_helper(root);}
};
```

tree_builder function:

```
void QuadTree::tree_builder(TreeNode *&p, ...)
{
    p = new TreeNode();
    p->id = new int[2 * length]; 
    ...
}
```

delete_helper function, that's where I get the error:

```
void QuadTree::delete_helper(TreeNode *& p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            delete_helper(p->child[i]);
        }
        delete[] p->id;
        delete p;
        p = NULL;
    }
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    QuadTree *tree;
    tree = new QuadTree(length, xyseed);
    ...
        delete tree;
    ...
        return 0;
}
```

P.S. Sorry my code is long, I tried to make it as short as I can!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. A short example is great, but only if it can still produce the described error. There is not enough information in your example to deduce the source of the problem.

Comment: What's the call stack of the exception?

Comment: Why are you deleting `p->id` four times?

Comment: You have some code and a problem. The next step is to find where the problem is in the code. Either you have to post something that we can compile, or you have to get the stacktrace yourself, typically from a debugger.

Comment: Do not use raw pointers - you will not need to delete them. For id use std::vector

Comment: Where do you initialize to zeroes the 4 elements of `child`? If you don't then they will enter to the `if (p != NULL)` and try to delete them even though they are not pointing to an object.

Comment: @MondKin, I didn't initialized them at first. I did it now. Still gets the same error at `if (p != NULL)`!

Comment: @MondKin Thanks for your help and your hint to initialize the children. I found the problem. In the `tree_builder`, I defined a leaf node as `p->child[0] = NULL`. That caused the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're deleting p->id four times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    ....
    delete[] p->id;
}
```

Another potential problem is deleting uninitialized children because the child array isn't initialized to 0s. Are you sure every node has four valid children?

Comment: You are right and I fixed it, this can cause a problem; However, even I delete it after the for loop, I get the same error!

Comment: If you edit the question, you invalidate the answers. Since the problem is still happening, are you sure that every node has four children? Are you possibly deleting an uninitialized child?

Comment: Yes, every node has four children. And the delete_helper is the only place that deletes.

Comment: btw, the leaves nodes of the tree don't have any children.

Comment: Well then the leaf nodes are going to explode when they try to delete their children, right?

Comment: Initialize the child array to 0s just for fun and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I did it. I get the same error. It shows the same error when I only delete p too. And it's always stops at if (p != NULL).

Comment: Time to run valgrind or step through your code with gdb.

Comment: Hey Millie, thanks for your help and your hint to initialize the children. I found the problem. In the `tree_builder`, I defined a leaf node as `p->child[i] = NULL`. That caused the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. Glad you found out and thanks for checking back and letting me know.